# Error while saving Workbook using Aspose tool after Deleting a range of Cells

Tags: c#, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

Before saving the Workbook I am deleting a CellArea in the Worksheet(I have used ClearContents, DeleteRange, ClearRange). But it keeps on giving an error "**Specified argument was out of the range of valid values**." 
However if i remove the delete code and try it saving, It works fine..KIndly Suggest..
My Code goes like this :

```
foreach (GcmTemplateWorksheets _worksheet in Worksheetdetails)
        {
            if (_worksheet.IsTransposeRequired ?? false)
            {
                Range maxRange = _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.MaxDisplayRange;
                _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.ClearRange((int)_worksheet.StartRow, (int)_worksheet.StartColumn, maxRange.RowCount, maxRange.ColumnCount);
            }
            _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.ImportDataTable(data_.Tables[_worksheet.FixedWorksheetName], false, _worksheet.ExportDataStartRow ?? 0, 0);
            //Instantiate the error checking options
            ErrorCheckOptionCollection opts = _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].ErrorCheckOptions;
            int index = opts.Add();
            ErrorCheckOption opt = opts[index];
            //Disable the numbers stored as text option
            opt.SetErrorCheck(ErrorCheckType.TextNumber, false);
            opt.AddRange(CellArea.CreateCellArea(0, 0, _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.MaxDataRow, _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.MaxDataColumn));
        }
             string _exportPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportTemplatePath"].ToString();
        //Save the worksheet at an appropriate configured location and assign path to _exportPath..
        _workbook.Save(_exportPath);
        return _exportPath;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this scenario and during my testing, I had to update your code a bit accordingly (*as there are some objects/pointers or other options for which I am not sure about their values. So, I have to use a dummy DataTable and other objects/values accordingly for it*) to test his case using my sample input file (Book1.xlsx) with our latest version/fix: [Aspose.Cells for .NET v7.3.2.5](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FA80127BB8FA477!179&authkey=!APnkCUv5yDmDa6o) and as per my observations, it works absolutely fine. I did not find any issue.

Here is my complete runnable sample code with v7.3.2.5 (Please recommend the user to try it):

**Sample code:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(i / 10 + 1, "Item " + i.ToString(), i);
}
Workbook _workbook = new Workbook(@"e:\test2\book1.xlsx");
Worksheet _worksheet = _workbook.Worksheets[0];
Range maxRange = _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].Cells.MaxDisplayRange;
//workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.ClearRange((int)_worksheet.StartRow, (int)_worksheet.StartColumn, maxRange.RowCount, maxRange.ColumnCount);
_workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].Cells.ClearRange((int)maxRange.FirstRow, (int)maxRange.FirstColumn, maxRange.RowCount, maxRange.ColumnCount);
//workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.WorksheetName].Cells.ImportDataTable(data.Tables[_worksheet.FixedWorksheetName], false, _worksheet.ExportDataStartRow ?? 0, 0)
_workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].Cells.ImportDataTable(dt, false, 0, 0);
//Instantiate the error checking options
ErrorCheckOptionCollection opts = _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].ErrorCheckOptions;

int index = opts.Add();
ErrorCheckOption opt = opts[index];
//Disable the numbers stored as text option
opt.SetErrorCheck(ErrorCheckType.TextNumber, false);
opt.AddRange(CellArea.CreateCellArea(0, 0, _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].Cells.MaxDataRow, _workbook.Worksheets[_worksheet.Name].Cells.MaxDataColumn));
string _exportPath = @"e:\test2\ouput_book1.xlsx";
//Save the worksheet at an appropriate configured location and assign path to _exportPath..
_workbook.Save(_exportPath);
```

For your reference, I have also attached the resource files ([Book1.xlsx](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FA80127BB8FA477!178&authkey=!AKM3YT8RB726C_I), [ouput_book1.xlsx](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FA80127BB8FA477!177&authkey=!AD_zA8fC1gRi_p0)). If you still face any issue with the latest release, can you please share a runnable code/console application (he may use some dummy datatable dynamically for it too) to reproduce the issue on our end. You can also post the query in [Aspose.Cells product support forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your vivid Response.. I had figured out that i was somehow passing wrong parameters into the ClearRange method which was making the Workbook not save at the end..